# Tensor form of $\nabla \times (\phi \vec{V})$

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors

So i'm given to find the tensor/index notation of this Vector identity:

(1) $\nabla\times(\phi{V})=\phi(\nabla\times\vec{V})-\vec{V}\times(\nabla\phi)$

would this just be

$$=\partial_i\epsilon_{ijk}\phi_i\vec{V}_je_k$$

or since $\phi$ is a scalar

$$=\phi\big(\partial_i\epsilon_{ijk}\vec{V}_je_k\big)$$

I'm not pretty good with tensors or index in general so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Although $\phi$ is a scalar, it is not a constant, so it doesn't commute with $\partial_i.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $e_k$ is the ordinary constant ON-basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then we have
$$
[\nabla \times (\phi V)]_k
= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i (\phi V)_j
= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i (\phi V_j)
= \epsilon_{ijk} ((\partial_i \phi) V_j + \phi (\partial_i V_j)) \\
= \epsilon_{ijk} (\partial_i \phi) V_j + \epsilon_{ijk} \phi (\partial_i V_j)
= \epsilon_{ijk} (\partial_i \phi) V_j + \phi \epsilon_{ijk} (\partial_i V_j) \\
= [\nabla \phi \times V]_k + \phi [\nabla \times V]_k
$$
so
$$
\nabla \times (\phi V)
= \nabla \phi \times V + \phi \nabla \times V.
$$

Comment: shouldn't it be $\nabla\times(\phi V)=\nabla\phi\times V-\phi\nabla\times V$?

Comment: @Samishafi. My equation is the same as your equation (1). Do you think that your equation is incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in my text book it says that it's $-$ i'm not sure why. I'm using boas 3rd edition.

Comment: I got positive aswell,but the book tells me it's negative for the second part of the eq

Comment: @Samishafi. Could you show me exactly what the book says that it should be?

Comment: this is exactly how the book says it should be $\nabla\times(\phi{V})=\phi(\nabla\times\vec{V})-\vec{V}\times(\nabla\phi)$

Comment: what i don't get is the negative $V\times \nabla\phi$

Comment: is it perhaps cause you tried for $k$? I did it for $i$ and got + $V\times \nabla\phi$

Comment: @Samishafi. The cross product is anticommutative: $u \times v = - v \times u$. Therefore, $\nabla \phi \times V = - V \times \nabla \phi$.